# Dynamic SQL runtime column type

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

Some of you may think I am doing the worst thing ever to a stored procedure but it's just a experiment at this time, this is what I am doing,

```
CREATE procedure [dbo].[Flags_Update]
(
    @UserID nvarchar(255),
    @CategoryID INT,
    @ProductID INT,
    @PropertyName nvarchar(255),
    @PropertyValue nvarchar(max)
)
AS
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(500);
SET @sql = 'UPDATE Flags SET ' + @PropertyName + ' = ' + @PropertyValue + ' WHERE Flags Flags.CategoryID =' +  @CategoryID + ' AND Flags.ProductID ='+  @ProductID;
EXEC(@sql);
IF (@@ROWCOUNT=0)
    BEGIN
        SET @sql = 'INSERT INTO Flags(UserID, CategoryID, ProductID, '+ @PropertyName + ') VALUES(' + @UserID + ', ' + @CategoryID + ', ' + @ProductID + ', ' + @PropertyValue + ')';
        EXEC(@sql);
    END
GO
```

When executing I am getting this error,

> Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'UPDATE Flags SET
>   IsRelased = 1 WHERE Flags Flags.CategoryID =' to data type int.

#### I know the error is coming up because in procedure propertyName is nvarchar(255) when column type is INT, how can I overcome this error ?

Please note that some property column will be nvarchar and some will be INT

**EDIT**

I did a clever thing and decided to have each property column have `nvarchar(255)` as datatype but I am still getting this error.

**EDIT 2**

Casting as suggested by Martin below but getting this error now,

> An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a
>   condition is expected, near 'Flags'

Comment: Since you already know the reason why it's failing, use [`sp_executesql`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms188001.aspx) instead of `EXEC` and pass `@PropertyValue`,`@CategoryID` and `@ProductID` as parameters to `sp_executesql`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is occurring because some of your parameters in the `SET @sql` statement are `INT` values.

Try `CAST`ing (or `CONVERT`ing) the `INT` fields to `NVARCHAR`s.  You will need to do this throughout your code where you concatenate text and numbers.

```
SET @sql = 'UPDATE Flags SET ' + @PropertyName + ' = ' + @PropertyValue + ' WHERE Flags Flags.CategoryID =' +  CAST(@CategoryID AS NVARCHAR) + ' AND Flags.ProductID ='+  CAST(@ProductID AS NVARCHAR);
```

Note that I have changed `+  @CategoryID +` to `+ CAST(@CategoryID AS NVARCHAR) +`, and so on.

Comment: The problem is simply that you are concatenating a `NVARCHAR` and an `INT`, the parameters can remain `INT` values with no issue.

Comment: You are right + 1, i was thinking it wrong way, thanks, however I am getting this error now, An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'Flags'.

Comment: You should perhaps raise that as a separate question as it is unrelated to your original one, however, I believe that the problem here is that you are using `@PropertyValue` (which is text) as a value in your `VALUES` list without putting quotes around it.  Try putting `''' + @PropertyValue + '''` to rectify.